# How to add XML declaration to xml with XMLBeans

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have this question about Java XMLBeans. I want to include the following declaration at the top of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Is there anyway to do this natively with XMLBeans? The above can always be concatenated as String to the xml content but that's ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a processing instruction.  That's the XML declaration (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl).  Processing instructions start with "<?" but cannot start with "<?xml" (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-PITarget).  So is the question about XML decl or PIs?

Comment: It's about XML declaration. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` construct is an *[**XML declaration**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)*.

Per [org.apache.xmlbeans.save(ContentHandler ch, LexicalHandler lh)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28org.xml.sax.ContentHandler,%20org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler%29):

> Writes the XML represented by this source to the given SAX content and
>   lexical handlers. Note that this method does not save the XML
>   declaration, including the encoding information. **To save the XML
>   declaration with the XML, see [save(OutputStream)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream%29), [save(OutputStream,
>   XmlOptions)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream,%20org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions%29), [save(File)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.File%29) or [save(File, XmlOptions)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions%29)**.