# How to create a typical XML Header with XML Beans in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I would like to create a specific xml document with XML Beans. So I have been reached an acceptable result like this one:

```
<Req accessId="1234" ver="1.1">
   <Loc id="007" maxNr="5">
      <Altitude x="123" y="987" type="ABC"/>
   </Loc>
</Req>
```

Now a need the XML Documents´s typical XML Header, but I not found a solution by using XMLBeans. This is that I need as result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Req accessId="1234" ver="1.1">
   <Loc id="007" maxNr="5">
      <Altitude x="123" y="987" type="ABC"/>
   </Loc>
</Req>
```

The Java Code, which create the XMl Result on console:

```
    XmlOptions options = new XmlOptions();

    Map<String, String> substNameSpaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
    substNameSpaces.put("ext", null);

    options.setSavePrettyPrint();
    options.setLoadSubstituteNamespaces(substNameSpaces);
    options.setUseDefaultNamespace();
    options.setSaveOuter();

    // ReqDocument
    ReqDocument doc = ReqDocument.Factory.newInstance(options);

    // Req
    Req req = doc.addNewReq();
    req.setAccessId("1234");        
    req.setVer("1.1");

    // Loc
    Loc locValReq = req.addNewLoc();
    loc.setId("007");
    loc.setMaxNr(5);

    // Altitude
    Location location = loc.addNewAltitude();
    location.setX(123);
    location.setY(987);
    location.setType("ABC");

    // Outline
    System.out.println(req.xmlText(options));
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please show us some code how you create the XML?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205060/how-to-add-processing-instruction-to-xml-with-xmlbeans